# Remove the intro banner when logged in

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com

The visibility of the top banner on [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com) seems to be controlled by a cookie instead of being tied to the account. Every time I restart my browser or clear my cookies, I see the "Stack Exchange Q&A communities are different. Here's how:" message.

[image: top banner on stackexchange.com]

Can it be permanently hidden for logged in users? While we're at it, can the banner be removed across all sites, even if I haven't joined them? I find myself joining sites just to get rid of the "Here's how it works:" message.

[image]

Comment: Or maybe logged in users who have taken the tour? Some people join right away but don't know this info... if they take the tour, they should know it already.

Comment: Or logged in users who have one positive scored post on the network?